# I have a 403 error on my Joomla homepage, but the page still renders. What could be causing it?

Tags: joomla, http-status-code-403

I manage this website: https://www.llscientific.com/ which is built with the Joomla Placebo template and running on Joomla 3.7.3.

The problem is that the homepage returns a 403 error even though it continues to display the page in full with all its assigned content. The other pages on the site return 200 and display properly.

These are the things I have checked so far without seeing any change:

1. File and folder permissions, 644 and 755, respectively
2. Verified that the config.php file is set to 444
3. Changed the default template from Placebo to something else
4. Disabled plugins one by one (cleaning cache and rechecking)
5. Disabled content modules on the homepage to see there is something there that is causing the error

Comment: Where are you seeing the 403?  If it is a 3rd party tool like GTMetrix, Pingdom, etc, it might be that their server is in a country that is blocked, etc.

Comment: Thanks! I am checking using Firefox Web Developer tools and also a Chrome plugin by Ayima. Both show a 403.